# Why my Base64 encoded image could not show properly in img tag?

Tags: lit, lit-html

I'm trying to use base64 to show an image, BUT it only shows the encoded string but not the image.

I copied it to a new file, and it showed correctly.

This is the code:

```
@customElement('image-board')
export class ImageBoard extends LitElement {
    // ...

    @property()
    imgSrc = ""

    render() {
        var img = ""
        if (this.imgSrc != "") {
            img = `<div> <img src="data:image/png;base64,${this.imgSrc}" /> </div>`;
        }

        return html`
            <div id="image-setter">
                ${img}
                <input type="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
                <button @click=${this.setImage}>Set Image</button>
            </div>
        `
    }

    // ...
}
```

I use `lit` to build my components.

I'm sure that my imgSrc could either be an empty string or a valid base64 encoding image.

I've tried a smaller image (150 x 100 px) but it still could not run correctly.

[incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tWKh.png)

However, the following is exactly what I want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izchg.png)

But I implement it by adding another img tag out of the component like:

```
<img id="outside-image"></img>
<image-board></image-board>
```

and set it's src by

```
let node = document.getElementById("outside-image");
node.src = `data:image/png;base64,${this.imgSrc}`
```

I'm confused that why it can not display correctly just by:

```
img = `<div> <img src="data:image/png;base64,${this.imgSrc}" /> </div>`;
```

PS: I'm not an English-speaker, so some expressions may not be accurate.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using Base64 `data:` URIs instead of using the far superior `URL.createObjectURL()` approach?

Comment: I don't use Lit, but looks like you need ``unsafeHTML`` https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#unsafehtml

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks, I didn't though of `unsafeHTML` anyway. My problem has been solved.

Comment: Yes @Dai , for I fetch my image by interacting with golang (through `wails`). Using string and base64 is much more easier than any other ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to render the `img` HTML string, you need to pass it to the `html` template literal **again**. For example...

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  render() {
    const base64 = '<some base64 image string>';

    // !!! pass the HTML string to `html` template literal again
    const img = html`
      <img src="${base64}" />
    `;
    
    return html`
      <div>${img}</div>
    `;
  }
}
```

See this [lit playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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) demo in action